# Smooth approximation of the hinge loss function

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, machine-learning

I came across a paper but the smooth approximation for the hinge loss function is wrong. Can someone guide me to the proper smooth approximation (using polynomials) of the function $$h(x)=\max(0,1-x)$$ which is exact when $|x| \ge \rho$, where $\rho$ can be made arbitrarily small?

Comment: You might as well work with $max(0,-x)$, which makes your bound involving $\rho$ make sense. And then you can work with a fixed $\rho$ ( $= 1$, say)

Comment: But I don't know if you can do it with polynomials.

Comment: The paper that you have linked works only for UIUC; please fix the link so that others can see what paper you are referring to.

Comment: Also, what about the approximation in: http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/writing/smoothHinge.pdf

Comment: Sorry about the link. The paper can be viewed here: http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/homes/afarhad2/index_files/scene_discovery.pdf. 

Actually, I found the proper coefficients for the order 4 polynomial. The paper has a typo on page 5. Instead of $\frac{3}{2}x$ it should be $\frac{1}{2}x$. 

The link for the smooth quadratic hinge function was a great help. Thanks Suvrit.


Comment: Hi Bernard, I expanded my comment into an answer because you found the information helpful.

Comment: @Bernard - do you mean smooth as in infinitely differentiable or once differentiable?

Comment: The link is dead, as well as the one in the comments. Some reference info should have been added. A DOI link being perennial, it should be preferred when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the details for those who might feel too lazy to chase the links in the comments above.

The *Hinge loss* for $x \in R$ is defined as
$$H(x) = \max(0, 1-x)$$

Jason Rennie in his article "Smooth Hinge Classification" describes the following *smooth* version of the Hinge loss (a smoothed version was being sought because of discontinuity in the derivative at $x=1$).

Rennie defines (the definition seems natural enough that somebody might have also found a similar one; I will be happy to be corrected) the *smoothed Hinge loss*:
$$H_s(x) = \begin{cases} \tfrac{1}{2}-x & x \le 0,\\\\
\tfrac{1}{2}(1-x)^2 & 0 < x < 1\\\\
0 & x \ge 1
\end{cases}$$

This loss is smooth, and its derivative is continuous (verified trivially).

Rennie goes on to discuss a parametrized family of smooth Hinge-losses $H_s(x; \alpha)$. Additionally, several other variations are possible, depending on what numerical behavior seems more appropriate for an application.

Comment: Note that $H_s$ is $C^1$, not smooth in the usual sense (infinitely differentiable) (this is for random students wandering by, in case they are confused)

Answer (score 0):

The paper *Differentially private empirical risk minimization* by K. Chaudhuri, C. Monteleoni, A. Sarwate (Journal of Machine Learning Research 12 (2011) 1069-1109), gives two alternatives of "smoothed" hinge loss which are doubly differentiable.

The paper is [linked here (pdf)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/chaudhuri11a/chaudhuri11a.pdf); the approximations are given p.14-15 (p.1082-1083 in journal); see the [extract 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou3wn.png) and 
[extract 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcFOo.png).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but it seems worth noting that the requested hinge function is probably the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss). This is different from the ones discussed in other answers, and actually has a parameter $\rho \geq 0$ that can be made arbitrarily small. It can be defined as

$$
h(x ; \rho) = \begin{cases}
1 - x & \text{ if } x \leq 1 - \rho \\
\frac{1}{4\rho} (1 - x + \rho)^2 & \text{ if } 1 - \rho < x \leq 1 + \rho \\
0 & \text{ if } x > 1 + \rho
\end{cases}
$$

As in the other answers, this is not "smooth" in the infinitely-differentiable sense, but it is in $C^1$. It is straightforward to show that $\lim_{\rho \rightarrow 0} h(x ; \rho) = \max(1 - x, 0)$ and it is exact for $|x - 1| \geq \rho$. This hinge function is sometimes used in SVMs [e.g., [1](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11634-008-0020-9.pdf),[2](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume17/14-526/14-526.pdf)]. Here's a quick plot:

[image: plot of hinge function]